# How to fix BCP file with widechar support that causes Pentaho data integration to fail on insert of values from first character of first row?

Tags: bcp, pentaho-data-integration, widechar

I have an bat file that collects data with a bcp extract call that executes a Stored Procedure(SP) with the -w flag.  When the data from that file is consumed by our Pentaho transformation, there is an additional character added to the first value in any row.  The CSV input step uses "UTF-16LE" but the first field has a value that has garbage characters before the value (ex. "ï»¿1" instead of "1"). Is there an additional option to bcp that can either add a header row or is there something that can cleanse this character from the pentaho side.

Sample BCP command : 
bcp "exec [companyschema].[collectdataprocedure] %SESSIONID%" queryout collectedoutput.csv  -t "," -w -T -S

The issue occurs when I try to load to the database within the transformation.

I have tried skipping the first row of the data but do need to have that data loaded to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to the issue and it is to use the Replace in String step with Search Pattern of 
`"([^A-Za-z0-9\-])"` and set Empty String "Y" to replace the first field in your row with the same name.

This resolved the issue with losing the first row of data.